# How to initialize BOW or Skipgrams in Word2vec embeedings?

Tags: python, nlp, data-science

I am not able to find the good source where i can able to find out how to initialize BOW or SKipgrams.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "initialize"?
Which version of word2vec are you using? In [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) the default training is CBOW, you can train the skip-gram using the parameter `sg=1`